# Joining two tables with reference to multiple columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way I can join two tables based on multiple columns in SQL Server?

I have two tables.

Table 1 is:

```
id |   Code   | column 2| column 3| column 4 | 
---+----------+---------+---------+----------+
 1 |   ABC    |   6     |   6     |   9      |
 2 |   XYZ    |   7     |   7     |   10     |
 2 |   MNO    |   6     |   6     |   10     |
 3 |   XYZ    |   6     |   7     |   10     | 
 3 |   PQR    |   5     |   6     |   3      |
 4 |   ABC    |   9     |   8     |   8      |
 5 |   MNO    |   1     |   2     |   6      |
```

Table 2 is :

```
id | column 1 |  Result
---+----------+--------------
 1 |   ABC    |  Pass
 2 |   XYZ    |  Pass
 2 |   MNO    |  Fail
 3 |   PQR    |  Fail
 5 |   MNO    |  Pass
```

Now I want to join the two tables with reference to two columns, on the basis of `ID` and `CODE`. I want all the rows from table 1 and put the result in only matched row of table 1.

My final result should be like this:

```
id |   Code   | column 2| column 3| column 4 | Result
---+----------+---------+---------+----------+--------
 1 |   ABC    |   6     |   6     |   9      | Pass
 2 |   XYZ    |   7     |   7     |   10     | Pass
 2 |   MNO    |   6     |   6     |   10     | Fail
 3 |   XYZ    |   6     |   7     |   10     | 
 3 |   PQR    |   5     |   6     |   3      | Pass
 4 |   ABC    |   9     |   8     |   8      |
 5 |   MNO    |   1     |   2     |   6      | Pass
```

Query I used so far is

```
select 
    tb1.*, tb2.result 
from 
    table1 tb1
left join 
    table2 tb2 on tb1.id = tb2.id and tb1.code = tb2.column1
```

Is this query correct one as I am getting duplicate rows on table 1 ?

Comment: You probably want to `left join table2 tb2` not `left join table1 tb2` https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wwceg1qusDP2Pz9zEBzFyT/0

Comment: i did the same . sorry, it was a typing mistake.

Comment: Your query is correct.

Comment: i also think so , but i am getting few duplicate rows in table 1

Comment: @SqlProgrammer did you look at the demo link in my comment? your query works fine

Comment: "In SQL Server", but the tags include MySQL and Oracle but not SQL Server? Please note the tags at the bottom of your post; when you post, Stackoverflow will guess, but it will often guess wrong, you must override what it puts there by default. For now I will edit the tags (which you can do, too - you just won't need now, since I will be doing it for you).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use INNER JOIN:

```
select tb1.*,tb2.result from table1 tb1
INNER JOIN table2 tb2
on tb1.id = tb2.id and tb1.code=tb2.column1
```

[image]